# DataFrame apply function based on multiple column and set value for multiple columns as well

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(5,4)*10).astype(int), columns=list('abcd'))
def cal(a, b):
    if a + b > 5:
        return a+b, a-b
```

how could I apply this function to df, the two variables cal take would be df['a'] and ['b'], the output a+b, a-b will be set to df['c'], df['d'].

loop the df works, but How could I use apply or applymap to achieve this (maybe cal need to be tweak)?

Comment: What happens if the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: then the values would be the original values in df['c'] and df['d'].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can vectorize this using mask:

```
vals = pd.concat((df['a'] + df['b'], df['a'] - df['b']), axis=1).values
df[['c', 'd']].mask(df['a'] + df['b'] > 5, vals)
Out: 
    c   d
0   6   3
1 -12   3
2  12 -14
3  21 -31
4  15 -21
```

where the original df is

```
df
Out: 
   a   b   c   d
0  3  -2   6   3
1 -4  -8 -12   3
2 -1  13  10  -4
3 -5  26 -21  17
4 -3  18  14  19
```

Comment: Hi Ayhan, Thanks a lot. This works. what if we don't use the logic of the function? if I need to do by someway to call this function (assume the logic of the function is very complicated), instead of using the logic, is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    (np.random.randn(5, 4) * 10).astype(int),
    columns=list('abcd')
)

df

    a   b   c   d
0 -21 -12 -19 -22
1  -3   0   3   3
2   7   7  -6   3
3  -3  -4  -9  -1
4   7 -15   6   4
```

---

Use `dot` and multiply the appropriate transformation

```
v = np.column_stack([df.a.values, df.b.values])
w = np.column_stack([df.c.values, df.d.values])
trans = np.array([[1, 1], [1, -1]])

df.loc[:, ['c', 'd']] = np.where(v.sum(1, keepdims=True) > 5, v.dot(trans), w)

df

    a   b   c   d
0 -21 -12 -19 -22
1  -3   0   3   3
2   7   7  14   0
3  -3  -4  -9  -1
4   7 -15   6   4
```